# A question about being correctly decidable

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I feel like a bit of an idiot, but I can't figure this question out:

> Suppose any sentences $X$ and $Y$ are correctly decidable in any arbitrary system $S$, then $X \rightarrow Y$ is also correctly decidable

Using the definition that if a sentence is correctly decidable it is either provable and true or refutable and false, I have got:

There are four cases: $X$ and $Y$ both true and provable, $X$ true and provable and $Y$ false and refutable, $X$ false and refutable and $Y$ true and provable, or $X$ and $Y$ both false and refutable.

I see how this relates to the truth or falsity of $X \rightarrow Y$, via the truth table: eg. if $X$ and $Y$ are both true and provable then $X \rightarrow Y$ is true. But why would it be provable?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What proof rules are you using?  Whatever they are, a proof that $X$ is true concatenated with a proof that $Y$ is false should give you a proof that $X \Rightarrow Y$ is false.  Similar reasoning with the other cases should give you a proof that $X \Rightarrow Y$ is true.

Comment: 1) $Y$ is *true* and *provable*. $Y \to (X \to Y)$ is *valid*, and thus provable. Being $Y$ provable ($\vdash Y$), by *modus ponens* we have that $\vdash (X \to Y)$. In addition, being $Y$ true, by truth table for $\to$, also $X \to Y$ is true.

Comment: So provability works in the same way as truth? $X \rightarrow Y$ is provable if either $X$ and $Y$ are both provable or $X$ is refutable and $Y$ is provable?

Comment: $X \to Y$ is provable if either $Y$ is provable or $X$ is refutable.

Comment: 2) $X$ is *false* and *refutable*, i.e. $\vdash \lnot X$. Now we have to use the tautology $\lnot X \to (X \to Y)$.

Comment: Thank you Mauro, I understand!

Comment: @Atlas  Not quite the same way.  It's entirely possible for $X \Rightarrow Y$ to be provable with neither $X \text{ nor } Y$ being provable *or* refutable.  For example, $\operatorname{CON} (ZF) \Rightarrow \operatorname{CON} (ZF+CH).$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your system includes standard propositional logic, you can prove $X \to Y$ from $Y$ or from $\neg X$.